# Appending JSON data in table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a table like this:

```
scan_time   credential  status      asset_code

value10     value12     value13     value14
value20     value22     value23     value24
value30     value23     value24     value25
```

And I have a JSON data something like this:

```
[
  {
    "scan_time": "Oct. 18, 2013, 6:27 p.m",
    "credential": "iexactlyknow",
    "status": 1,
    "asset_code": "you10"
  },
  {
    "scan_time": "Oct. 18, 2013, 6:20 p.m",
    "credential": "302E32325F302E30",
    "status": 2,
    "asset_code": "10001"
  }
]
```

I want to append JSON data in table something like this:

```
scan_time                   credential         status       asset_code

Oct. 18, 2013, 6:27 p.m     iexactlyknow          1         you10
Oct. 18, 2013, 6:20 p.m     302E32325F302E3       2         10001
value10                     value12            value13      value14
value20                     value22            value23      value24
value30                     value23            value24      value25
```

Is it possible to do?

If appending 2 rows is difficult then you can consider just 1 row to append,
and then you can consider data something like this:

```
[
  {
    "scan_time": "Oct. 18, 2013, 6:20 p.m",
    "credential": "302E32325F302E30",
    "status": 2,
    "asset_code": "10001"
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anythin' already?

Comment: yea I tried and but not getting desired results...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily, see the code below. I didnt type out all the columns, but just loop of your json data and essentially fill a template and adopt the generated html to your table.

```
var $table = $("table#mytable");
function addRowsFromData(data) { //data is an array of objects as specified - parse json first
    var rows = "";
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        rows += "<tr><td>" + val.scan_time + "</td><td>" + val.credential + "</td>" + /*the rest of your columns*/ ;
    });
    $table.prepend(rows);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any result using the above script... 
Unresolved function or method adopt...

Comment: $table.adopt was not working,so I tried append.But now its adding rows in bottom instead of on top

Comment: @Pradeep Sorry, my bad been working with another lib lately - I'll make the changes to fix that